# Find a symmetric point on a line

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I'm given a point $A (2; -6; 5)$, I need to find a symmetric point of A in regards of the straight line:
$$
2x+y+9z+5=0
$$
$$
x-3y+5z-4=0
$$

I began by making the line equation into parametric equation, which is:
$$
x=-32t-61
$$
$$
y=t
$$
$$
z=7t+13
$$

The problem I am facing, is that I don't know how should I move forward.

Edit: What I did now, is that I found a plane, on which the point A is and which's normal vector is the t values on the parametric equation. I found the intersection point of the line and the plane (by substituting the parametric equation's values into the plane equation) and then, because the point I needed to find, had to be symmetric to point A and the line, the point C (the symmetric point) was found with Cx=2Ox-Ax (where O is the intersection point of the plane and the line). With that logic, I found that the symmetric point of A in regards of the line is $C(2056/537; -5300/537; 2101/537)$, but the given answer is $C(4; 2; 3)$. Did I make a mistake or the given answer is wrong?

Plane equation which I got with $n * AP = 0$ is:
$$
-32x+y+7z+35=0
$$

By substituting the parametric values into it, I got:
$$
-32(-32t-61)+t+7(7t+13)+35=0
$$
which is
$$
1024t+1952+t+49t+91+35=0
$$
which is
$$
1074t = -2078
$$
where
$$
t = -1039/537 => y
$$

By checking the value of t, you can already see that the answer for the point wont be anywhere near as "beautiful" as the given answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}\DeclareMathOperator{\proj}{proj}$If $\ell$ is the line through some point $\Vec{x}_{0} = (x_{0}, y_{0}, z_{0})$ and having direction vector $\Vec{v} = (a, b, c)$, then a point $\Vec{x} = (x, y, z)$ decomposes as
$$
\Vec{x} = \Vec{x}_{0} + \underbrace{\Vec{x} - \Vec{x}_{0}}_{\Vec{w}}
= \Vec{x}_{0} + \underbrace{\proj_{\Vec{v}} \Vec{w}}_{\parallel \Vec{v}} + \underbrace{\Vec{w} - \proj_{\Vec{v}} \Vec{w}}_{\perp \Vec{v}},
$$
and the "symmetric point" is the image $R(\Vec{x})$ under reflection in $\ell$, namely
\begin{align*}
  R(\Vec{x})
  &= \Vec{x}_{0} + \proj_{\Vec{v}} \Vec{w} - (\Vec{w} - \proj_{\Vec{v}} \Vec{w}) \\
  &= \Vec{x}_{0} - \Vec{w} + 2\proj_{\Vec{v}} \Vec{w}.
\tag{1}
\end{align*}
This formula may be easier to use than your method once you have the line in parametric form.

---

Your parametric equations check out, i.e, the resulting line lies in each plane, so your answer looks plausible (unless the problem has been mis-copied): Take
$$
\Vec{x}_{0} = (-61, 0, 13),\qquad
\Vec{v} = (-32, 1, 7).
$$
Since $\Vec{x} = (2, -6, 5)$, you have $\Vec{w} = \Vec{x} - \Vec{x}_{0} = (63, -6, -8)$,
\begin{align*}
  \proj_{\Vec{v}} \Vec{w}
  &= \frac{\Vec{v} \cdot \Vec{w}}{\|\Vec{v}\|^{2}}\, \Vec{v}
  = \frac{-2016 - 6 - 56}{1024 + 1 + 49} (-32, 1, 7)
  = -\frac{1039}{537} (-32, 1, 7), \\
\Vec{w} - \proj_{\Vec{v}} \Vec{w}
  &= (63, -6, -8) + \frac{1039}{537} (-32, 1, 7),
\end{align*}
and
$$
R(\Vec{x}) = (-61, 0, 13) - (63, -6, -8) - \frac{2078}{537} (-32, 1, 7).
$$